# Is it possible to change the default user account directory names in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

Is it possible to change the default user directory names, such as:

- Downloads -> dl
- Applications -> app
- Documents -> doc
- etc…

In Linux, you can change those in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file.

Comment: I don't know about changing them, but you could probably make some sort of alias to them, if that will accomplish what you need

Comment: I use the terminal a lot, for managing files, programming, etc. So I like simple name and clutter free directories. An alias would solve one of the problems, but would clutter the directory. I was hoping those names could be changed.

Comment: Oh I hear you.  I dev on my mac all the time.  I suggest you create a workspace directory and then work out of there.  For instance, with my setup, my Documents folder has a "workspace" directory, and then every new folder in there is a new project and such.  I don't use Pictures, Videos, etc. at all, ever.  Downloads and Applications I left alone since they worked for me